# How to print a value of parameter inside of function in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a function **pluralizeParam(n, word, pluralWord)** with these requirements:

- If n is 1, return the non-plural word (parameter word);otherwise, add an “s” to the plural word;
- If the pluralWord parameter is provided, instead of adding an “s,” return the pluralWord.

What I have done so far is following:

```
function returnPluralWord(n, word, pluralWord) {
    if (n === 1) {
        return word;
    } else if (n === 1 && (word.lastIndexOf("s")) || (word.lastIndexOf("ess"))) {
        return word + "s";
    } else if (n !== 1 && word.length - 2 === "es") {
        return word + "s";
    } else if (pluralWord !== 'undefined') {
        return pluralWord;
    }
}

var result = returnPluralWord(2, "lioness", "lionesses");
console.log(result);
```

My problem is: it is not printing **pluralWord**. How do I do that?
Thanks

Comment: Your second condition will never be executed; you've already handled `n === 1`, but more to the point, move your 4th case second.

Answer (score 2):

`word.length - 2` can't never be equal to `"es"`. You need also to rearrange your statements, the 2nd is already catched by 1.

When you use the `word.lastIndexOf('s')` ( which is wrong logic I think ), it returns the last index of the `s` character, not if it ends on `s`.

You can check [**String#endsWith**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith) and [**String#startsWith**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith) methods, these ones check if the string starts or ends with the given part

```js
const str = 'less';
console.log(str.endsWith('s'))
```